# Issues renaming notebok tab widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

How can I rename a notebook tab?

this is my code

```
    style = ttk.Style(tabmain1)

    style.configure('lefttab.TNotebook',tabmargins=[2, 5, 0, 0],tabposition='wn',justify= "left",padding= [0, 0], font=("helvetica 155"))

    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(tabmain1, style='lefttab.TNotebook')

    tab0 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tabControl.add(tab0, text="Messages ")
```

in another page i run

```
from gerateste import tabControl,tab0
tabControl.add(tab0, text="test, it works")
```

but its not working, can someone help

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens when you do? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your first script requires `__all__` list to pass necessary objects to your other script. All `tkinter`and `ttk` objects are managed using `grid`

```py
"""gerateste.py
"""

__all__ = ["tk", "ttk", "tabmain1", "style", "tabControl", "tab0"]

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

tabmain1 = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(tabmain1)

style.configure('lefttab.TNotebook',
                tabmargins=[2, 5, 0, 0],
                tabposition='wn',
                justify= "left",
                padding= [0, 0],
                font=("helvetica 155"))

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(tabmain1, style='lefttab.TNotebook')
tabControl.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

tab0 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab0.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

tabControl.add(tab0, text="Messages ")
```

Your other script looks like this. Note the valid use of wildcard import due to the target script containing `__all__` to define exactly what will be imported.

```py
"""new_script.py
"""

from gerateste import *

tabControl.add(tab0, text="test, it works")

tabmain1.mainloop()
```